# Limit of the log of a sequence

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the convergence of a random variable $X_n$, I was able to get to a point where I have 
$$\frac{1}{n}\log(X_n) \rightarrow (\log2 - 1)$$
in the almost surely sense. I found a solution elsewhere on this forum saying that from this relation we can conclude that $\log(X_n) \rightarrow - \infty$ noting that $\log(2) - 1$ is a negative constant. Is that a correct statement and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_n = \log(X_n)$. If $Y_n/n \rightarrow \alpha := \log(2)-1 < 0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N$ such that 
$$\alpha + \epsilon > \frac{Y_n}{n}, \quad \forall\; n \geq N.$$
Therefore, $n(\alpha + \epsilon) > Y_n$. Choose $\epsilon = \alpha/2$, and you find $0 > n\alpha/2 > Y_n$ for any $n$. This is the desired result.